# Custom keys sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I updated to Sublime Text 3 and now all my `custom Keys` are gone. I try to reset them, but it does not work.

I tried in `Settings User` as well as in `Key Bindings User` this:

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
// and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
[
     { "keys": ["cmd+shift+c"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
     { "keys": ["cmd+shift+b"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
]
```

as well as

```
 // Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
 // and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
 {
      "keys": ["cmd+shift+c"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false },
      "keys": ["cmd+shift+b"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true },
 }
```

No Luck! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. First, you can copy `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` from your old Sublime Text 2 folder (`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User`) and place it in the same ST3 folder (`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`).

Alternatively, you can remake the key bindings. Open **`Sublime Text → Preferences → Key Bindings—User`** and add the key bindings like so:

```
[
     { "keys": ["cmd+shift+c"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
     { "keys": ["cmd+shift+b"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } }
]
```

Make sure there is no trailing comma `,` after the last entry.